# javascript on updatepanel

Tags: asp.net

How do you run a script as the updatepanel begins. I have a gridview inside an updatepanel and when the user clicks to sort or to change page, I'd like to run a script just as the postback begins.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the beginRequest event handler. You can see the documentatio [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397432.aspx). If you have more than one update panel with update mode Conditional you will need to inspect the request to see which update panel is being updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a script on the client before postback, you could add a "OnClick" handler (client side, so OnClientClick for a server side control) and do whatever you want in there.  The form won't post back until that script is finished and returns true.